# How to multiply each corresponding elements in two arrays when using Cplex

Tags: cplex, mixed-integer-programming

There are Two arrays `A1[a][c], A2[b][c]`

Now I am trying to multiply each corresponding elements of these two arrays.

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 5;

range aRange = 1..a;
range bRange = 1..b;
range cRange = 1..c;

int A1[aRange][cRange] = [[1,2,2,1,3]
                          [1,1,1,1,1]
                          [1,1,1,1,1]];

int A2[bRange][cRange] = [[2,2,2,2,2]
                          [2,3,1,3,2]];


dvar boolean x[a][b];
```

If decision variable choose `x[1][2]` then I want to get a result of an array of multiply each corresponding elements, `[1*2,2*3,2*1,1*3,3*2]` like this.

Additionally, want to get a value of `1*2+2*3+2*1+1*3+3*2=19` :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 5;

range aRange = 1..a;
range bRange = 1..b;
range cRange = 1..c;

int A1[aRange][cRange] = [[1,2,2,1,3],
                          [1,1,1,1,1],
                          [1,1,1,1,1]];

int A2[bRange][cRange] = [[2,2,2,2,2],
                          [2,3,1,3,2]];

int R[i in aRange][j in bRange]=sum(k in cRange) A1[i][k]*A2[j][k];

execute
{
writeln(R);
}
```

gives

```
[[18 19 0 0]
         [10 11 0 0]
         [10 11 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

for all (c in cRange) 
        sum(a in aRange, b in bRange) x[a][b] *A1[a][c]*A2[b][c]

But the right hand side is missing. Do you want to formalize a constraint or objective function? Are you familiar with the generic mathematical model notation?

Comment: Sir, I am not good at coding at all. So I couldn't understand what generic mathematical model.
And, I coded what you wrote, but there is an error of 'syntax error, unexpected forall' .
 Is it because I write the code in "maximize" objective function?

Comment: Yes. You can't use the for all statement in the objective. I think your decision variable is missing the index c, then you can sum over all indices in the objective. But I don't know the model you try to solve. You should really try to start from scratch and get known to the mathematical notation, before you try to implement them on the computer.